# How to use "cdn_cache_id" in the custom response header?

Tags: google-cloud-cdn

In the [docs](https://cloud.google.com/load-balancing/docs/custom-headers#variables), I see that "cdn_cache_id" can be used as a header value, but I received an "Invalid header value" error when using it. I tried to apply it using Cloud Shell and UI, but it's the same. Can anyone confirm what really happened here?

[image: cdn_cache_id error]

Comment: This appears to be a bug: the correct value is indeed `{cdn_cache_id}`, but the UI (if you Ctrl/Cmd+Space) will show `{cache_id}`. I've filed a bug to have this fixed ASAP. In the meantime, you can use gcloud via Cloud Shell, which works:

`➜  gcloud beta compute backend-services update serverless-backend --custom-response-header='X-Frame-Options: DENY' --custom-response-header='Cache-Status: {cdn_cache_status}' --custom-response-header='Cache-ID: {cdn_cache_id}'`

Comment: Ok, I'll go with Cloud Shell from here. Thanks @elithrar.

Comment: This is now fixed and live.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As it was mentioned by *@elithrar* at the comment section, this issue was reported and Google Engineers are aware of this issue.

You can keep track of the issue report status by following [this thread](https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/171940583) at [Google Public Issue Tracker](https://cloud.google.com/support/docs/issue-trackers).

**EDIT** This is now fixed, and the input field validation now (correctly) accepts `{cdn_cache_id}` in Console:

[image: CDN]